# Symfony2 json response

Tags: json, mongodb, symfony

I have trouble with the follow code

```
/** @Route("/{collection}/{id}", name="object", defaults={"_format" = "json"}) */
public function retrieveOne($collection, $id)
{
    $collection = Inflector::classify($collection);

    $object = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager')
        ->getRepository('NameBundle:' . $collection)
        ->find($id);

    $response = new Response(json_encode($object));

    return $response;
}
```

Document

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as Mongo;

/**
* Entrada
*
* @Mongo\Document
*/
class Entrada
{
    /**
     * @Mongo\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Mongo\String
     * @var int $type
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @Mongo\String
     * @var string $nombre
     */
    private $nombre;

   //.. setters and getters
}
```

and always i get `{}` in the response body.

**NOTE**: the query returns a object correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode` will only encode public properties.

So you could:

- Make you properties public (baaahhhh)
- Create a toArray() method on your Entrada class, and just do `json_encode($object->toArray())`
- Use the awesome [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle)